# commit somebody/yourself to doing something

Tags: phrase-structure

This is from [a news article](https://news.yahoo.com/missing-titanic-submersible-titan-search-rescue-north-atlantic-oceangate-172526242.html) :

> At a Tuesday afternoon press conference, Coast Guard Capt. Jamie
> Frederick would not **commit to searchers being** able to perform a
> rescue, even if they were able to find the sub, which he said had
> "about 40 hours of breathable air" left.

I looked up the verb 'commit' in [the OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/commit?q=commit) and learned it is used in this structure :

> to promise sincerely that you will definitely do something
>
> **commit somebody/yourself to doing something**
>
> *Borrowers should think carefully before committing themselves to
> taking out a loan.*

So I think "**commit to searchers being**" should be corrected to 'commit searchers to being'.

Or is "**searchers**" the subject of the gerund "**being**" (and "**searchers' being**" is the object of preposition "**to**")?

Comment: The sense is "he would not commit [himself] to guaranteeing that the searchers would be able to perform a rescue".

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, it doesn't mean to commit to promise to do something:

from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit):

> **2 c :** to reveal the views of
> *refused to commit himself on the issue*

This means Frederick refused to *give the opinion (view)* that searchers would be able to perform a rescue.

Comment: Thank you very much.